# How to get/set network connection through Appium for an android device

Tags: android, python, wifi, appium

I try to use Appium to test my android device:
The basic work I need to do is to get the network connection status.
Environment: [Appium Server v 1.4.0 on Windows 7 + Python Client 0.16]

```
from appium import webdriver

desired_caps = {}
desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '4.4'
desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'SamSung Galaxy Note4'
desired_caps['browserName'] = 'Chrome'


driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
driver.get('http://google.com')
print driver.contexts
print driver.network_connection
time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

However, when I run the script, I just got the below output:

```
> [u'NATIVE_APP', u'WEBVIEW_1'] Traceback (most recent call last):  
> File "D:/PycharmProjects/Work/hello/Work_YM/Appium/sample_1.py", line
> 15, in <module>
>     print driver.network_connection()   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\appium\webdriver\webdriver.py", line
> 601, in network_connection
>     return self.execute(Command.GET_NETWORK_CONNECTION, {})['value']   File
> "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
> line 195, in execute
>     self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\appium\webdriver\errorhandler.py", line
> 29, in check_response
>     raise wde selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: "unknown command:
> session/31fe15845b2580877c1900c31d8f688d/network_connection"
```

It seems the network_connection(which is a property of webDriver) doesn't work, anyone can give some help?
Thanks!

Comment: I didn't find a way to get/set network settings via Appium. Use an alternative way:                                                                                   `adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.settings/.wifi.WifiSettings  <br/>                                                                                                                      adb shell input keyevent 19 & adb shell input keyevent 23`

Answer (score 0):

You can get/change network connection settings through `AndroidDriver`. However, it works only for Android version less than 5.

```
AppiumDriver<WebElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL("..."), caps);
NetworkConnectionSetting networkConnection = new NetworkConnectionSetting(false, true, false);  // airplane mode, wiif, data

networkConnection.setData(true);  // enable mobile data
networkConnection.setWifi(false); // close wifi

((AndroidDriver<WebElement>)driver).setNetworkConnection(networkConnection);
networkConnection = ((AndroidDriver<WebElement>)driver).getNetworkConnection();
```

Answer (score -1):

The following code may fix your problem.

```
NetworkConnectionSetting ncs = new NetworkConnectionSetting(false, true, false);
driver.setNetworkConnection(ncs);
System.out.println(ncs.toString());

ncs.setWifi(false);
driver.setNetworkConnection(ncs);
System.out.println(ncs.toString());
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your answer so that it has some introduction which relates to the question plus some explanation how it works/ helps. Code-only answers are usually not too helpful, your code does not even comments inside.